# SQL SELECT statement error with datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, select

Something is wrong with statements with datetime field:

MyDB:

```
id  name   datetime
1   test1  2011-04-28 19:37:44
2   test2  2011-04-28 21:27:04
```

When I run the following statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ('datetime' > '2011-04-28 21:00:00')
```

I get all - test1 and test2

When I run this statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ('datetime' = '2011-04-28 21:27:04')
```

I get nothing

When I run the following statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ('datetime' > '2011-04-28 21:00:00')
    AND ('datetime' < '2011-04-29 21:00:00')
```

I get nothing

Why?

Comment: are you sure your datetime field is a real datetime field, and not varchar? What db are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the field name "datetime" into quotes and MySQL treats it as a string, not a column.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE datetime > '2011-04-28 21:00:00';
```

Comment: +1 Actually every DBMS treats `'datetime'` as a string literal and `datetime` as a column name.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing string comparisons, i.e. comparing the **string** "datetime" to a certain date.

Change your query to

```
...WHERE ([datetime] = '2011-04-28 21:27:04')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually putting the `datetime` column name in single quotes? If you are, it means you are comparing the string `'datetime'` to the string `'2011-04-28 21:00:00'` which doesn't make much sense. In SQL, if something is surrounded in single quotes it is usually a string literal.

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE datetime > '2011-04-28 21:00:00'
```

Or more likely:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE datetime > to_date('2011-04-28 21:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Note: That `to_date` function and the format string are specific to Oracle, you did not specify which database you are using and these functions tend to be db-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the column name:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (datetime > '2011-04-28 21:00:00')
```

In your query, you are comparing the `string` "datetime" against another `string`, consisting of numbers.

Alphanumerically, numbers come before letters, so the "datetime" string is greater than the numeric date string you are comparing against.